# Case class copy does not maintain state of an inherited trait

Tags: scala

Say I define a trait and case class that extends it:

```
    trait A {
        var list: List[Int] = List()
        def add(i: Int) = list = i :: list
    }

    case class B(str: String) extends A
```

If I then create an instance of B, modify the list and make a copy of it, the copy takes the values of the list as defined in trait A:

```
    val b = B("foo")
    b.add(3)
    println("B: " + b.list)
    println("Copied: " + b.copy(str = "bar").list)
```

Output:

> B: List(3)
>
> Copied: List()

I know this is probably not good functional programming practice anyway, but is there a way I can force the copy of B to take the altered version of the list for instance b?

Comment: No automatic/declarative way to handle that as "not good functional programming"

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by declaring the list in the case class, and satisfy your trait's type by declaring a method. So:

```
trait A {
    def list: List[Int]
}

case class B(i: Int, var list: List[Int]) extends A
```

And then your example:

```
scala> val b = B(2, List(1))
b: B = B(2,List(1))

scala>  b.list = List(3)
b.list: List[Int] = List(3)

scala>  println("B: " + b.list)
B: List(3)

scala> println("Copied: " + b.copy(i = 4).list)
Copied: List(3)
```

I don't know what you're doing that requires a mutable list in your class, but I imagine that even though this satisfies your example it might not satisfy whatever problem you're working on since:

```
scala> val a: A = b
a: A = B(2,List(3))

scala> a.list
res2: List[Int] = List(3)

scala> a.list = List(4)
<console>:15: error: value list_= is not a member of A
       a.list = List(4)
```

When trying to view an instance of `B` as an `A` you won't be able to assign the list type. If you were dealing with an instance of A you'd have to do something like

```
scala> a match {
     | case itsAB: B => itsAB.list = List(4); itsAB
     | case other => other
     | }
res3: A = B(2,List(4))
```

But either way, this is how you'd do it. Either that or you can follow phongnt's advice to create a non-case class and define a copy method yourself.

In a comment you said:

> I failed to mention that the trait attribute needs to be modifiable with a reference to the trait itself

But this sounds like global mutable state to me. If you really need that, *and I encourage you to not to* then you can use an object:

```
object A {
   @volatile
   var list = List.empty[Int]
}
```

But I doubt this gets at what you're expressing in your question either since there is not an individual list still per instance here. So... looking at your updated question, I can only guess that something like this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
object A {
   @volatile
   var list = List.empty[Int]
}

trait A {
   def list = A.list
   def add(i: Int) = A.list = i :: A.list
}

case class B(str: String) extends A
```

Which lets you:

```
scala> val b = B("hi")
b: B = B(hi)

scala> b.add(0)

scala> b.add(1)

scala> A.list
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 0)
```

But again, this is global mutable state, it's not a good thing. It's not threadsafe. So if there's a way for you to figure out your problem without doing this... I'd encourage you to do so.

Comment: I failed to mention that the trait attribute needs to be modifiable with a reference to the trait itself so unfortunately again this solution does not work. Have further clarified the question

Comment: _trait attribute needs to be modifiable with a reference to the trait itself_
What you're talking about is global mutable state then. In which case it can't really be in a trait, it has to be in an Object and wouldn't be accessed from an instance but from the `A.list = `

Comment: @user79074 looking at your updated question and guessing at what you're really trying to do, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `copy` method is generated for you by the compiler when you declare a case class and it is only parameterised with the variables you define in the case class

Hence, you can definitely have `copy` method do that for you by declaring the variable `list` in the case class e.g. `case class B(i: Int, list: List[Int])`. You will also need `override val` modifier to satisfy scalac. However, scalac doesn't allow you to override a mutable variable, so you need to change the trait too, for example

```
trait A {
  val list: List[Int] = List(1)
}

case class B(i: Int, override val list: List[Int]) extends A
```

Comment: The trait attribute has to be a var in this case unfortunately. I have updated the post to clarify this

Comment: You can still use var in both the trait A and B if you don't provide the implementation in A. If you must have both var & default variable, then you might opt for non-case class and define a copy method yourself