# Why Scala case class copy method parameterised only with the variables defined in the case class?

Tags: scala

Why Scala case class copy method parameterised only with the variables defined in the case class?

The question based on on the Q&A:

[Case class copy does not maintain state of an inherited trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812293/case-class-copy-does-not-maintain-state-of-an-inherited-trait)

Short summary - when trait is defined with a field and extended by a case class, `copy` on the case class will create the new class instance only with the variables defined in case class, without the extended trait.

```
 trait A {
    var list: List[Int] = List()

    def add(element: Int) = {
      list = element :: list
    }
  }

  case class B(str: String) extends A {
    val b = B("foo")
    println("B1: " + b.list)

    b.add(1)
    b.add(2)
    b.add(3)
    println("B2: " + b.list)

    val b2 = b.copy(str = "bar")
    println("B3: " + b.list)
    println("B4: " + b2.list)
  }
```

Here, `B4: ()` will be empty, while `B3:(3,2,1)`

Comment: Note that you should reconsider using case classes if you're going to embed mutable state in them - in most cases a case class should be immutable.

Comment: BTW. I ran your code and B3 was (3,2,1) while B4 was empty (the inverse of what you said in the question).

Comment: I find the comment by @cchantep in the linked question a completely satisfactory explanation, quote: 'No automatic/declarative way to handle that as "not good functional programming"' When implementing `copy` for case classes, they simply didn't think about this use case, and didn't prevent `copy`-codegen, and also didn't emit an error or at least a warning. Maybe you could just submit this as an issue in the scala compiler, so that it at least outputs a warning...

Comment: @JakubKozłowski Regarding mutability - of course. It's just for the sake of example. Regarding B3 & B$ - thanks. Of course it should have been the other way around.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - Interesting. So you think it's just a case of 'haven't thought about this use case'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no reasonable way to do what you want consistently.

For your example, generated code for `copy` could be

```
def copy(str: String = this.str, list: List[Int] = this.list): B = {
  val newB = B(str)
  newB.list = list
  newB
}
```

Good enough. Now what happens if you change `list` to be private, or a `val` instead of a `var`? In both cases `newB.list = ...` won't compile, so what code should the compiler generate?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep the value of `list` after copying (considering the mutability issue I mentioned in the comments of OP), you can write your own `copy` method.

```
case class B(str: String) extends A {
  def copy(str: String = this.str, list: List[Int] = this.list): B = {
    val newB = B(str)
    list.reverse.foreach(newB.add)
    newB
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because the compiler treats case class fields in this special way only if they are defined in its primary constructor - and mind that only the first argument list is treated that way. For example, you wouldn't be able to modify fields using the copy method if they were defined in the second argument list.

Comment: Another idea that just popped out is that you could make the `list` field abstract in the original trait (as in, uninitialized), and then use `override var list: List[Int] = Nil` in the case class's primary constructor: `case class B(str: String, override var list: List[Int] = Nil) extends A`